# Minecraft Forge modding 1.8 instance changing tool/armor material + color

Tags: minecraft-modding

I am developing a minecraft mod in forge, and I need to find a way to create tools and armor where individual instances of items would have different tool material properties, armor material properties, and hues in how they are displayed. If you can offer help for any of those things, or for how to achieve these dynamic properties in general, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure about Forge in specific, but back in Bukkit a few years back, I managed to get custom NBT tags saving data regarding items. You might look into working with NBT tags for setting and storing custom properties on items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Forge aswell, but it is possible to change the nbt tags of individual items in Minecraft. I doubt that there is no implemenation of changing NBT data in Forge. Just google it! :-)